# again covered color after pause in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer with a black background and white text.  To get a faded bullet after a pause, I need to specify the color of the again colored text.  How can I do that?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which uncover settings you use, beamer will mix the foreground and background colour of the text to get the dimmed look of covered items. You can to some extend control the dimmed colour via the background colour of the text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<2> test
  \end{itemize}
  \only<3>{abc}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=green}
\usebeamercolor*{normal text}

\begin{frame}
  abc 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<2> test
  \end{itemize}
  \only<3>{abc}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you need more control, e.g. a different colour for still covered and again covered text, you could use the `\temporal` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \temporal<2>{\color{red}}{}{\color{green}} text
  \pause[3]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```